# OpenCvでグレースケール画像を表示すると白が黄色になる。

Tags: python, opencv

OpenCVでグレースケール画像を作成しようとしてますが、表示すると白色の部分が黄色になっているようです。
環境はwindows10、jupyternotebook、python3.6、OpenCv3です。
原因は分かりますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 以前回答頂いた内容が削除されていたため、自分で記載しておきます。plt.gray()を追加すればウィンドウをグレースケールモードで表示できて解決しました。参考url:http://programming.blogo.jp/python/matplotlib/grayscale_image_opencv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんな話でしょうか。

[jupyter notebookでOpenCV 3.1を動かす(2)](http://takacity.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-142.html)

Comment: まさにこの話です。無事解決しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: スタックオーバーフローへようこそ && 回答ありがとうございます。リンク切れになった時のため、それから検索でここに飛んできた人のために、回答にあたる箇所を引用しておくと、より多くの人に役立つ回答になります！（回答は、投稿後も編集できます）

Answer (score 1):

```
# RGBフォーマットからグレースケールのフォーマットに変えていますが、
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# imshowは「BGRフォーマットを引数」にとり、「カラーで表示」させるためのものなのでこれだけでは白黒にはなりません。
plt.imshow(gray_img)

# なのでこの一行を足します
plt.gray()

# 表示
plt.show()
```

私も同じところでハマりました。ww